# Electron-Phonon Hamiltonian and One-particle Approximation

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, phonons

Consider a hamiltonian with electron-phonon coupling, for instance, a very simple version of Holstein hamiltonian:  $$t\sum_k \hat{c}^\dagger_k \hat{c}_{k+1}+\text{h.c.}+\hat{b}^\dagger \hat{b}+\alpha \sum_k \hat{c}^\dagger_k \hat{c}_k \left(\hat{b}^\dagger+\hat{b} \right),$$ with just one phononic mode. 
The fermionic part alone, since there are no many body terms (of the type $\hat{c}^\dagger\hat{c}^\dagger\hat{c}\hat{c}$) can be solved in the one-particle approximation, and we can construct the wave-function as a Slater determinant.

However, when considering the electron-phonon hamiltonian, the only approach that comes to mind is to go to the many-body representation to solve the problem. Is there something like the one-particle approximation that can be used on such hamiltonians?  Does the wavefunction have any particular structure (such as the Slater determinants in the case of fermions without many-body terms) than can be exploited to simplify the treatment of the model?

In ther fermionic case, the one-electron approach makes the problem extremely less costful to solve numerically. With the electron-phonon coupling, however, it looks like the complexity is equivalent to a many-body problem, such as the Hubbard model. Is that correct, or is there any simpler approach that I am overlooking?

Comment: Since there's not been much interest here yet, perhaps you could try at [Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) since that site exclusively takes advanced-level questions like this, and has no high-school-level homework questions occupying the users' time.